# Month of Date() object is 3, but iPhone Simulator say's it's april

Tags: javascript, date, ios-simulator, titanium, titanium-mobile

I get JSON from a server and parse it to an array.

The date.month propery is "03", this is then added to a Date() object var date = new Date(year, month, day);

I convert the Date() object with date.toLocaleDateString()and the output in the iOS simulator is "April 5, 2012".

How can this be?!?!?!

JavaScript and JSON source is here: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/133958/month-of-date-object-is-3-but-tolocaledatestring-says-april

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript Date objects track months as 0 through 11. January is 0, in other words, so April is 3. If your server-side code thinks months are 1 through 12, you just subtract one when making a JavaScript Date.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's months start at 0, not 1, so month 3 is actually the 4th month. Don't ask me why they decided to make it this way.